# In $Q[x]/(x^2-2)$ find inverses of $[3x-2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, rational-numbers

---

In $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$

- Find inverses of $[3x-2]$

Comment: 1. You'll get better luck just asking one question at a time.  2. Since your equivalence classes are $[ax+b]$, the outcome of a multiplication should be something of this form.  You can find it without the division algorithm, since $x^2=2$ in this quotient ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do to complicate:

$$(3x-2)(ax+b)=3ax^2+(3b-2a)x-2b$$
and thus, $$(3x-2)(ax+b)=k(x^2-2)+1\iff(3a-k)x^2+(3b-2a)x-2(k-b)-1=0\iff...$$

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you write $[3x-2]=3r-2$, where $r^2=2$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{3r-2}=\frac{3r+2}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}=\frac{3r+2}{18-4}=
\frac{3}{14}r+\frac{1}{7}
$$

More generally, any element of your field can be written in a unique way as $a+br$, with rational $a$ and $b$, not both zero. Then
\begin{align}
(a+br)^{-1}
&=((a+br)(a-br))^{-1}(a+br)\\[6px]
&=(a^2-2b^2)^{-1}(a+br)\\[3px]
&=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}a+\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}r
\end{align}
and you know that $a^2-2b^2\ne0$ (why?).

Comment: One might argue that the question has been posed in an unfortunate manner, and that finding the reciprocal of $3\sqrt2-2$ is a standard exercise in high-school algebra.

Comment: @Lubin Or that the OP didn't realize it was just this easy.